# 1752. Check if Array Is Sorted and Rotated

Tags: c++, function, sorting, rotation, stdvector

Given an array `nums`, return `true`* if the array was originally sorted in non-decreasing order, then rotated **some** number of positions (including zero)*. Otherwise, return `false`.

There may be **duplicates** in the original array.

**Note:** An array `A` rotated by `x` positions results in an array `B` of the same length such that `A[i] == B[(i+x) % A.length]`, where `%` is the modulo operation.

**Example 1:**

```
Input: nums = [3,4,5,1,2]
Output: true
Explanation: [1,2,3,4,5] is the original sorted array.
You can rotate the array by x = 3 positions to begin on the the element of value 3: [3,4,5,1,2].
```

**Example 2:**

```
Input: nums = [2,1,3,4]
Output: false
Explanation: There is no sorted array once rotated that can make nums.
```

**Example 3:**

```
Input: nums = [1,2,3]
Output: true
Explanation: [1,2,3] is the original sorted array.
You can rotate the array by x = 0 positions (i.e. no rotation) to make nums.
```

I have a solution thats failing to pass some testcases. Can you tell whats wong with my solution.

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool check(vector<int>& nums) {

        int n = nums.size();

        int Break = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
            if(nums[i] > nums[i + 1]){
                Break = i;
            }
        }

        if(Break == n - 1){
            return true;
        }

        else {
            for(int i = Break + 1; i < n - 1; i++){
                if(nums[i] > nums[i + 1]){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
        
    }
};
```

Comment: Does your code work correctly if there are multiple breaks in the sorted order? I imagine you also need to compare the first and last element

Comment: The second `for` loop is pointless. The first loop only remembers the last (most recent, rightmost) break, and so elements to the right of that break are guaranteed sorted. Besides, having at most one break is necessary but not sufficient: e.g. `[1,2,4,3]`  only has one break, but nevertheless is not a rotation of a sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the second for loop

```
for(int i = Break + 1; i < n - 1; i++){
    if(nums[i] > nums[i + 1]){
        return false;
    }
}
```

you need to check that `nums[i]` and `nums[i+1]` are not greater than `nums[0]`.

Pay attention to that the function parameter should be declared with qualifier `const` because passed vectors are not changed within the function and the member function itself should be declared with qualifier `const`.

Here is a possible function implementation shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    class Solution
    {
    public:
        bool operator ()( const std::vector<int> &nums ) const 
        {
            std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0;

            if (!nums.empty())
            {
                while (( ++i != nums.size() ) && !( nums[i] < nums[i - 1] ) )
                {
                    //  empty body
                }

                if ( ( i != nums.size() ) && !( nums[0] < nums[i] ) )
                {
                    while ( ( ++i != nums.size() ) && !( nums[0] < nums[i] ) && !( nums[i] < nums[i-1] ) )
                    {
                        //  empty body
                    }
                }
            }

            return i == nums.size();
        }
    };

    std::vector<int> v1 = { 3, 4, 5, 1, 2 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = { 2, 1, 3, 4 };
    std::vector<int> v3 = { 1, 2, 3 };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    std::cout << Solution()( v1 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << Solution()( v2 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << Solution()( v3 ) << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
true
false
true
```